# Multi-variable functions' minimisation with Gradient method. Why the function of subsequent iteration points is strictly decreasing?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

If we assume, that the iteration origin $x^0 $ is fixed. With Gradient method we can get a sequence $(x^k)_{k \in N}$, where $x^{k+1} = x^k - \alpha_k f'(x^k)$. If $f'(x^k) \neq 0$ then for suffieciently small $\alpha_k$ a decreasing function can be guaranteed, that is, $f(x^{k+1}) < f(x^k)$.  I don't get why it is so, couldn't  $f'(x^k) $ be negative? Also, why there is a need for sufficiently small $a_k > 0$?

Comment: Do you know that the negative gradient points in the direction of steepest descent?

Comment: @littleO ok, but then why the gradient that points in the direction of steepest increase is chosen? How to determine whether to put $+$ or $-$ before the $a_k$?

Comment: $\alpha_k$ has to be positive in the context of the definition above. Otherwise the sequence will 'walk' in the direction of positive gradient which is the direction of the steepest increase; i.e. it has to be $x_{k+1}=x_k-\alpha_kf'(x_k)$ with $\alpha_k\geq 0$.

Comment: The need for sufficiently small $\alpha_k$ comes from the desired property that you don't want to jump over your minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})$. By Taylor there exists a $\xi$ between $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$ with
\begin{align}
f(x_{k+1})-f(x_{k})&=f'(x_{k})(x_{k+1}-x_k)+ \frac{1}{2}(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2f''(\xi)\\
&=f'(x_{k})(-\alpha_kf'(x_k))+ \frac{1}{2}(-\alpha_kf'(x_k))^2f''(\xi)\\
&=\alpha_kf'(x_{k})^2\cdot(-1+ \frac{\alpha_k}{2}f''(\xi))
\end{align}
If $f''(\xi)\leq0$ it follows for arbitrary $\alpha_k\geq0$ $$f(x_{k+1})-f(x_{k})\leq0.$$
If $f''(\xi)>0$ and $\alpha_k<\frac{2}{f''(\xi)}$ you get for the case $\alpha_k>0$, $f'(x_{k})\neq0$
$$f(x_{k+1})-f(x_{k})<0,$$
or for the more general case $\alpha_k\geq0$ and $f'(x_{k})$ arbitrary
$$f(x_{k+1})-f(x_{k})\leq0.$$